# How to prevent windows from idle time proccessing

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have a very bad experience from Windows 10, since when I leave my laptop for some minutes and it becomes idle, Windows starts some processing (that honestly I do not know what is it about), and suddenly the CPU fan starts to work at the highest speed, and makes noises that is not there at normal usages (imagine I leave the work to take a short nap, and some minutes later a storm coming out of my computer!), and immediately after that I move finger on touch pad or any other interaction, the situation comes back to normal.

I want to know what is this huge processing that never ends (I have this experience for almost two years) and how to stop it from happening?

Comment: This is not a Windows 10 issue (not in the half-decade I have been using it in production).  Do a full scan with Windows Defender to look for viruses (likely). Open MSCONFIG, boot tab, set for Clean Boot. Restart with a minimal set of processes / services.  See what it does. Add back services in small groups to see what process / service is causing the issue

Comment: @John What do you say about this: https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/100-cpu-usage-when-idle-for-2-minutes.3330373/

Comment: That article talks about the idle time process (which does, of course, run) but that process does not use up CPU resource.

Comment: @John Quote from there: "Windows uses idle times to run scans that it needs to run to keep PC working fine, so it could be rebuilding the index or defragging the hdd or just playing with superfetch, or run a defender scan. There are many other possible things it could be doing. It should go back to 0 the minute you interact with it"

Comment: You can look in Task Manager to see if these processes are running. Indexing will stop using CPU when done and does not hog CPU when working. If you have a HDD, turn defrag OFF for a bit. I do not use Superfetch at alll